# Setting inputType textFilter and textPassword stops displaying as password dots instead of themselves

Tags: android, xml

I have been trying to restrict the password field with a set of characters. So tried to use the textFilter and done it. When i set inputType textFilter and textPassword, it stops displaying as password dots and shows the text that i type in the Editext. When i remove the textFilter, then  characters of the field are displayed as password dots instead of themselves.

This is the snippet in used in my XML resource

**main.xml**

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2.0dip" android:singleLine="true"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:inputType="textPassword|textFilter"
                    android:hint="@string/input_field_here" android:digits="@string/only_alpha_numeric"></EditText>
```

**string.xml**

```
<string name="only_alpha_numeric">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/>
```

Please let me know , is there any possible way to achieve my desired result ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi use following lines in xml file . From this you can keep the textFilter property as well as password hint property too.. hope this will help you a lot.

android:password="true"
    android:inputType="textFilter"

Comment: what does textFilter do ?